# Chemical equation with multiple arrows in multiple directions

Tags: equations, chemfig, chemistry

I need to draw chemical equations with multiple arrows pointing out or in from a single "node". I tried rigging the curved arrow example given in the texdoc help for `chemfig` package.

The result is not pretty. The figure looks haphazard and assymetric. [image]

This can obviously be made much more symmetric. I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Take a look at this MWE

```
        \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{chemfig}
    
    \makeatletter
    \definearrow1{s>}{%
        \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
        \else
        \def\curvedarrow@style{shorten <=\CF@arrow@offset,shorten >=\CF@arrow@offset,}%
        \CF@expadd@tocs\curvedarrow@style\CF@arrow@current@style
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\curvedarrow@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@name)..controls#1..(\CF@arrow@end@name);
        \fi
    }
    
    
    \definearrow1{s<}{%
        \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@end@node)--(\CF@arrow@start@node);%
        \else
        \def\curvedarrow@style{shorten <=\CF@arrow@offset,shorten >=\CF@arrow@offset,}%
        \CF@expadd@tocs\curvedarrow@style\CF@arrow@current@style
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\curvedarrow@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@end@name)..controls#1..(\CF@arrow@start@name);
        \fi
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{document}
        
        \schemestart
        X\arrow(.90--.180){s>[+(10:0.8) and +(180:0.8)]}[10] Y
        \arrow(.0--.90){s<[+(170:0.8) and +(0:0.8)]}[-10]T
        \arrow(.-90--.0){s>[+(-170:0.8) and +(0:0.8)]}[-170] Z
        \arrow(.180--.-90){s<[+(-10:0.8) and +(180:0.8)]}[170]\,
        \arrow(.0--.180){s>[+(0:0.8) and +(180:0.8)]}[0]V
        \arrow(.0--.180){s<[+(180:0.8) and +(0:0.8)]}[0]
        \schemestop
        
    \end{document

}
```

Comment: Hi @magguu , two questions: do those connecting arrows need to be curved? Did you try the "matrix" examples on page 56 of the `chemfig` manual?

Comment: This is just a representative example. A simple case can possibly be drawn with straight arrows. But more complicated cases would look best if curved arrows are employed to required extent.

Answer (score 3):

Using the example on page 57 of the `chemfig` manual I came up with this solution to the alignment of the "compounds":

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
    \schemestart
        X   \arrow(X--V){->}
        V   \arrow(V--T){<-}
        T
        \arrow(@V--Y){0}[90,0.5] Y
        \arrow(@V--Z){0}[-90,0.5] Z
        \arrow(@X--@Y){->}
        \arrow(@X--@Z){->}
        \arrow(@T--@Y){->}
        \arrow(@T--@Z){->}
    \schemestop
    
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix connections]

Note the arrows are straight and not curved.

Comment: This looks good. I will try to see I can rig this to produce curved arrows.

Comment: Without using the new arrow macro you can use `\chemmove{}` to add and control curved arrows. Like this example between X and Y:  `\chemmove{ \draw[red,->, shorten <= 2pt, shorten >= 2pt] (X) .. controls +(90:1.4) and +(180:0.8) .. (Y);  }`

Comment: Why are there two arrows ```T \arrow(@V--Y){0}[90,0.5] Y``` and ```\arrow(@T--@Y){->}```? Are they drawing the same arrow twice?

Comment: No. The last one draws the arrow from T to Y. The first one is used to position Y directly above V using an invisible arrow of half length. The T is the last node of the line X - V - T. If you comment out the T and/or the first arrow, you'll get an error message. If you comment out the second arrow, you'll see T isn't connected to V.

Comment: Adding (X -- V) to the `\arrow` essentially says to TikZ to draw two named nodes X and V and connect them with an arrow. Those named nodes are used to draw the remaining arrows to connect all nodes.